# Native java to react native app covert playstore

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play-services

I have an app in playstore with 11k . The app is in native java.
i have made an react native app with same package name and changed the jks key to keystore file and changed version code too..
iam using the apps store jks file
i am getting this error i knowits resolve by uninstalling but I cant tell users to uninstall is there any other way
Execution failed for task ':app:installRelease'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package co.miaki.samplestickerappp signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

Comment: To provide an update to your existing users you may have to use the same jsk file as it might depend on the signatures

Comment: Sign your new app with the old keystore and same package name

Comment: i am using the the same jks file but i renamed to keystore! is that the prb?

Comment: It's probably that, you have to maintain the keystore as it is from your original app

Comment: now i have used the exact same file and i can upload it in plays tore too bundle file...but probles is when i update install i mean if i have the old version and i reinstall it crashed but it works fine if i uninstall old version..i cant tell users to uninstall? or it will act different when i upload in playstore!

Comment: Ensure that your JKS file and Keystore files/credentials are the same used for the actual app.

Comment: yes i have ensured that i took it from the old developer if it wasn't same it would gave me error when i upload in playstore

Answer (score 0):

so I have uploaded the apk in internal testing now it works. Its not giving an error. So my understanding is that google add another layer of security in app store that's why I couldn't install latest version on the existing google play version though I was using same key. Thank you all

Comment: Hi Sadman, I have the same scenario as yours. I want to update my Kotlin app in playstore with React-Native app (It is the same app, just get rewritten in React Native).
Now I'm doing some research to prepare my deployment and I found your question. 

So what is the final result of your deployment? Are the users need to uninstall their application first to avoid crash? Or do you found any other way? Please brief me with your preparation and deployment step :)

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: if u have the same key it will work fine brother..no crash or anything i have done internal test it will works fine. It just doesn't work  if we install the release apk without uploading playstore as play store adds another layer maybe that's why.

Comment: Ohh got it. So the reason you had crash when you test your new app because you install in manually (not from playstore) CMIIW. Thanks for the info brother!